# DNS resolve not working on linux ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, dns

when I try to change my DNS to any other DNS, nothing works as expected its like I set up nothing as DNS but i did!

when i open browser and try to open websites i get this error:

`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

---

I tried changing my DNS in :

`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

like this:

```
nameserver 178.22.122.100
nameserver 185.51.200.2
```

but after that when i open browser and try to open websites i get this error:

`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

---

And also I tried changing my DNS here :

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

like this:

```
DNS=178.22.122.100 185.51.200.2
```

and after/before that i done a systemd-resolved restart with this command:

`sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`

but after that when i open browser and try to open websites i get this error:

`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

---

I also tried this command :

`sudo resolvectl dns wlp3s0 178.22.122.100 185.51.200.2`

which sets shecan DNS directly to wlp3s0(my network adaptor), when i check `resolvectl status` it shows the following :

```
Link 3 (wlp3s0)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 178.22.122.100 185.51.200.2
```

but the DNS is not working as expected. when i open browser and try to open websites i get this error:

`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

---

When I try to ping these IPs they work:

```
$ping 185.51.200.2 -c 4
PING 185.51.200.2 (185.51.200.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 185.51.200.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=101 ms
64 bytes from 185.51.200.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=101 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 185.51.200.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=55.1 ms
64 bytes from 185.51.200.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=99.0 ms
64 bytes from 185.51.200.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=54.9 ms

--- 185.51.200.2 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, +1 duplicates, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 54.940/82.227/101.074/22.213 ms

$ping 178.22.122.100 -c 4
PING 178.22.122.100 (178.22.122.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 178.22.122.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=68.9 ms
64 bytes from 178.22.122.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=123 ms
64 bytes from 178.22.122.100: icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=66.3 ms
64 bytes from 178.22.122.100: icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=105 ms

--- 178.22.122.100 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 66.326/90.860/122.741/24.041 ms
```

---

EDIT: output of `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 May 25 15:24 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details about your network and IP addresses. Can you ping the specified servers?

Comment: @Bodo thanks for reply, i got ping from them and edited question, what kind on network information is necessary ? let me know and ill put them

Comment: Maybe a diagram of your local system, the DNS servers and your local network in between showing the IP addresses of the relevant systems. You wrote "the DNS is not working as expected". How exactly do you check this and what error or wrong result do you get?

Comment: @Bodo bro i dont know much about linux, just say commands and ill execute, lol. i check dns not working issue with openning browser and trying to use websites, websites not working and it shows ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: @Bodo is this fine now? can you leave me more replys please

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 thanks for reply, just added your request. do you want something else ?

Comment: Show the command and resulting output `host -v some.host.domain.tld` where you use a DNS name that cannot be resolved. You wrote "when I try to change my DNS to *any other* DNS, nothing works as expected". Did it work before your change? What was your DNS server before? You still didn't show or describe your network structure.

Comment: There is no command to show your network structure. I would expect something like this: My local computer has IP address X, it is connected via Ethernet to a router model ABC which has an internal IP address Y and external IP address Z, DNS server 178.22.122.100 is somewhere in the internet. There is a proxy / no proxy in my local network.

Comment: We're assuming this is a desktop installation and not a server installation, because you reference using a browser. What browser? On the surface, it appears your network is functional except DNS, but the problem could be one of many things, including the browser itself. In addition to describing your network layout requested by @Bodo, please update your question with the output of each of the following commands: `ip a`, `ip route`, `resolvectl`, `systemctl status systemd-resolved`, `systemctl status systemd-networkd`, `systemctl status network-manager`, `dig google.com`, `cat /etc/netplan/*`.

Comment: Other possible causes: those DNS servers (the name of one of them resolves to `dns.shecan.ir`) don't serve your IP, possibly limited to their own customers. Does `dig @185.51.200.2 google.com` or `dig @178.22.122.100 google.com` work on the commandline? If you `nmap -O 178.22.122.100`, does port 53 show as open?